I cannot connect to the internet in Android emulator
I have never encountered any problem like this. I have followed almost every possible way to fix this. I had wiped emulator and created new emulator too. I had 28 level api emulator, then I download 32 api level and created new device. I set 8.8.8.8 dns too. Then I deleted .android folder but still I couldn't connect to the internet in my emulator. does anybody has any idea what to do?


Hello I have already posted a fix in a similar question. please do have a look and tell me if it worked for you. below is the link of that article.
cannot connect to internet on emulater.
